# how to block ranges of ip addresses from tomcat6?

Tags: ip, tomcat6

I need to block country specific Ip ranges..
I tried blocking my own Ip address for an instance but it didn't happen.

I used the "Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127.0.0.1" deny=""" code inside the host tag in tomcat6 serverl.xml but it didnt help...

Please help me resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you specified allow, you should not specify deny. I believe deny has the precedence and deny="" allows anyone to connect.